# [Python]Calling method(self)

Tags: python, class, methods, abstract, self

I can not understand following commented line.
It's a python program.

---

```
class B:
 def bbb(self):
    method = self.commands[0]
    method(self) #I can't umderstand this line

class A(B):
    def aaa(self):
        print 'aaa was called'
    commands = [aaa]

c = A()
c.bbb()
```

---

Output:
aaa was called

---

I think above aaa method takes no arguments.
But to run this code, I need to pass "self" to aaa argument. Why? Are there any docs explaining this?What category this problem belongs?

Any simple codes are very welcome.
Because my English skill is too low.
So improving this question is welcome too.

I encountered this problem, when I was reading cpython/Lib/distutils/cmd.py:Command.get_sub_commands().

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the code sample is done makes it a little harder to tell what's going on. However, it's equivalent to:

```
child_methods = [] # a list of all the methods in `Child`

class Parent(object):
    def parent_method(self):
        print "parent_method() called"
        method = child_methods[0]
        method(self)

class Child(Parent):
    def child_method(self):
        print "child_method() called"

# add child_method to child_methods
child_methods.append(Child.child_method)
```

As you can see, `child_methods[0]` will actually be the function `Child.child_method`, which is a plain function, and not a bound method. It's not associated with an instance of `Child`, which is why you can and have to pass in the `self` yourself. You'd get a bound method from a `Child` instance with:

```
child_obj = Child()
bound_child_method = child_obj.child_method
```

This is made unclear by the fact Python will look up attributes in the type of an object if they're not found in the instance. For example:

```
# A dummy class to hold attributes
class Foo(object):
    pass

Foo.bar = 123 # we're adding an attribute to the type itself

foo1 = Foo()
print foo1.bar # prints 123
foo1.bar = 456 # this `bar` attribute "hides" the one on the type
print foo1.bar # prints 456
foo2 = Foo()
print foo2.bar # prints the 123 from the type again
```

This is why, in your code sample, `commands` is really a "global" variable, it just gets accessed confusingly through an instance of `B`. (This is not necessarily a bad practice if only objects of `B` or its children access this variable, but the lookup rules are a minor gotcha.)

Comment: Thank you.I understand "Unbound method" need to pass "self".

Comment: Exactly. If you added a *bound* method to the list, using, say `child_methods.append(Child().child_method)`, then that wouldn't be necessary - it'd use the `Child` instance you got it from.

Comment: It is not the same. In the code in the question, there is NO unbound method access. The value of `method` is a regular function.

Comment: "commands is really a "global" variable" `commands` is an attribute of `A` (as well as `B`), not a global variable

Comment: @newacct That's why "global" is in quotes. I meant it as a counterpart to an instance attribute which has a lifetime bound to an object, where a class attribute can mostly be thought of as just being in a different namespace. (Yes, classes are also object of which there only *usually* happens to be only one instance in a program, and functions accessed through a class instance become unbound method objects, but this level of detail about Python's internals would IMO make things less clear, not more.) I'll change the bit about an unbound method since that's flat out wrong.

Comment: @newacct I also used "equivalent" as in "works the same", not "is the same". Basically, I was trying to explain a Python-specific thing by analogy to more familiar concepts, instead of being pedantic about the semantics and inner workings of everything.

Answer (score 4):

Wow, this is confusingly written. Working backward from the code itself:

```
c = A()
```

Creates an instance of A. Looking at A:

```
def aaa(self):
    print 'aaa was called'
commands = [aaa]
```

This is a bit confusingly written; it makes more sense like this:

```
def aaa(self):
    print 'aaa was called'

commands = [aaa]
```

Defines a method `aaa`, then a *class variable* `commands` which contains `aaa` as an element. Now, looking at the next line of the program:

```
c.bbb()
```

Since `A` has no `bbb` and `A` inherits from `B`, we consult `B`:

```
class B:
 def bbb(self):
    method = self.commands[0]
    method(self)
```

Since we've established that `commands` is `[aaa]`, the first line means `method = aaa`. So the second line is effectively `aaa(self)`.

Comment: Thank you.But Why 'aaa(self)' not 'aaa()'.In this code,'aaa()' won't work.It's my question.

Comment: any method call on an object implicitly passes the object itself as the first parameter. Put another way, you can think of `c.bbb()` as `B.bbb(c)`. In this case, you could rewrite `aaa` not to need `self` (`aaa` would then have no parameters, while `bbb` would need to call `method()` instead of `method(self)`)

Comment: "the first line means method = aaa" Right, but `aaa` from what context? The variable `aaa` that you're referring to no longer exists at this point in the program.

Comment: Hm. I suppose it may be more accurate to say that it's `A.aaa`?

Comment: @ChadMiller: on Python 2.x, you'll find that `method != A.aaa`.

Comment: @newacct Ah, I'm used to Python 3 (I just did some REPLing to see that you are correct). Since, as far as I can tell, it doesn't substantially affect the correctness of the answer I'll just upvote your comments and leave them as a footnote, unless you or someone want to suggest an edit.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
method(self) #I can't umderstand this line
```

Calls the function `aaa()`. In your function declaration:

```
def aaa(self):
```

`aaa` does takes an argument (`self`). That's why you have to call it with `method(self)`.

Since `self.commands[0]` is a function, calling `method(self)` is equal to:

```
aaa(self)
```

Comment if you have something else to ask!

Comment: Thank you.It's True.I think Python automatically pass 'self' to first argument if its class method is bound method.But it's just my oppinion.

Comment: Yes, it does that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

By the way it is better to use new-style classes, class A(object):...

All methods of class in python have self as  first argument, except of class methods.
Here is example about self:

```
def x(first, arg):
    print "Called x with arg=",arg
    print first

class A(object):
     some_method = x

a = A()
a.some_method("s")`
```

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks